# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android', 'org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener'

Tags: java, android, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

  subprojects {
  project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
  }
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            118.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

when runnning --stacktrace command

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  line 26 :

  subprojects {
  project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
  }
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Build completed with 1 failures.
> org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

many lines there